# Why vite is ignoring files when transpiling typescript files, while tsc (Typescript compiler) does not

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vite, vitest

I am working on a VSCode extension. I want to start writing tests for the extension using [vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) but I am facing an issue where it is not transpiling all the test files, only the entry file.

This is my directory structure:

```
-- src
-- tests
   |-- runTest.ts
   |-- suite
      |-- index.ts
      |-- extension.test.ts
```

When I run `vite build`, only `runTest.ts` is transpiled, but if I run `tsc -p ./` it transpiles the entire `tests` folder.

Here is my `tesconfig.ts`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true, // I change this to false when running tsc compiler
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@extension/*": [
        "../src/*"
      ]
    },
    "rootDir": "."
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./tests/**/*.ts",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".vscode/**/*"
  ],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
  }
}
```

And this is my `vite.config.ts` file:

```js
import { builtinModules } from 'node:module';
import { resolve } from 'node:path';
import { configDefaults, defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
    optimizeDeps: {
        exclude: ['vscode'],
    },
    esbuild: {
        pure: ['console'],
    },
    test: {
        coverage: {
            exclude: [...configDefaults.coverage.exclude ?? '', '**/src/parser/*'],
        },
    },
    build: {
        target: 'esnext',
        minify: false,
        emptyOutDir: true,
        lib: {
            entry: [
                resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
                resolve(__dirname, 'tests/runTest.ts'),
            ],
            name: 'extension-name',
            fileName: '[name]',
            formats: ['cjs'],
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: [
                'vscode',
                ...builtinModules,
                ...builtinModules.map((module) => {
                    return `node:${module}`;
                }),
            ],
            output: {
                preserveModules: true,
            },
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@extension': resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
        },
    },
});
```

This is `runTest.ts` file: **(it was generated using VSCode `yo code`).**

```js
import * as path from 'node:path';

import { runTests } from '@vscode/test-electron';

async function main() {
    try {
        // The folder containing the Extension Manifest package.json
        // Passed to `--extensionDevelopmentPath`
        const extensionDevelopmentPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

        // The path to test runner 
        // Passed to --extensionTestsPath
        const extensionTestsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './suite/index.js');

        // Download VS Code, unzip it and run the integration test
        await runTests({
            extensionDevelopmentPath,
            extensionTestsPath,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to run tests', error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

The reason I want to use `vite` instead of `tsc` to compile the tests, is because I used `vite` to develop the extension and I want to use `vitest` to write the tests. `vitest` honors `vite.config.ts` config which makes them work perfectly together.

VSCode test files are run using [vscode-test](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-test) package.

I searched in rollup and esbuild config to see if an option need to be changed/added/removed but no result.

Comment: Why do you want to transpile the tests? `vitest` should be able to able to run them without doing that.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention that in my post. VSCode requires that. It only runs js files